# Temporary Date Range Table MySQL

Tags: mysql

first time poster long time reader. I was wondering if anyone know how to create a Temporary Table that generates a list of dates. Basically what I need this table for is so i can add 1 to each date which is between two other dates from a record. I keep getting errors in mySQL so i was hoping someone could correct me if you see a mistake.

```
set @start_date = ‘2014-07-29’;
set @end_date = ‘2016-07-29’;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Dates (
d DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (d))

WHILE (@start_date < @end_date)
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Dates (d) VALUES (@start_date)
SELECT @start_date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @start_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL has no loops outside of procedures or function, and the syntax is no Mysql syntax

> ```
> CREATE ProCEDURE mysatetable()
> BEGIN
> set @start_date = '2014-07-29';
> set @end_date = '2016-07-29';
>
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Dates (
> d DATE,
> PRIMARY KEY (d));
>
> WHILE (@start_date < @end_date) DO
> INSERT INTO Dates (d) VALUES (@start_date);
> SET @start_date :=  DATE_ADD(@start_date,INTERVAL 1 day);
> END WHILE;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL mysatetable()
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Dates
> ```
>
> ```
> | d          |
> | :--------- |
> | 2014-07-29 |
> | 2014-07-30 |
> ...
> | 2016-07-27 |
> | 2016-07-28 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec8fb6d6fb62666f8c4341cfd5c175dd)*